# How do I position a JLabel north but not completely at the top?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to position a label on top of an image. The label and image are both in a panel that is positioned in the center. I want my label to be above the image, but if I did `BorderLayout.NORTH` it would place the label as far up as it can.

How do I position it wherever I want, but still above the image?

Comment: `BorderLayout` is not the only layout manager... I suggest you take a look at some of the others, `GridBagLayout` for example, with `Insets`.

Comment: Or use nested layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `EmptyBorder` to the label. It is possible to specify all four padding integers. In these three GUIs, the top padding (only) is set to 0, 30 & 60 pixels.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class LabelPadding {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    static BufferedImage bi = 
            new BufferedImage(400, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    LabelPadding(int pad) {
        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("The top padding in px is: " + pad);
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(pad, 0, 0, 0));
        ui.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                for (int ii=0; ii<70; ii+=30) {
                    LabelPadding o = new LabelPadding(ii);

                    JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                    f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                    f.pack();
                    f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```